# Setting up IIS 7.0 to run ASP.NET 2.0 Application?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

How can I set up IIS 7 to run an ASP.NET 2.0 Application?

What steps do I need to take?

Comment: Is it that different from setting up an ASP.NET 3.0/3.5 application? I think not, but correct me, please, if I'm wrong!

Comment: Did you figure out how to set up your ASP.NET 2.0 Application?

Answer (score 0):

Install/Reinstall .Net Framework 2.0